# Looking for a reference in commutative algebra

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

I need "I.G. Macdonald, Secondary representation of modules over a commutative ring, Sympos. Math. 11 (1973) 23–43." in my research, but it seems to be very old and rare. Does anyone know a site for buying or downloading it? Thanks very much.

Comment: Do you have access to a university library? Often you can request scans of journal or conference articles.

Comment: here you can locate a library that has it: http://www.worldcat.org/title/symposia-mathematica-vol-11/oclc/472159513

Comment: Bodleian Library (Oxford University) will scan and email you this for £4.75. They accept Visa/Mastecard/JCB/Maestro...

Comment: http://www.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/__data/assets/pdf_file/0019/103483/PCAS-Dept-accounts-Scan-and-deliver-v2.pdf